# Are value objects valid dependencies for DI design pattern?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

For all DI examples I have seen, I always see the dependencies as other classes, like services. But an object may depend, heavily and/or crucially in fact, on configuration values such as Strings and resource wrappers (File/Path/URI/URL, as opposed to an entire big value string/document, or a reader).

Note, this is about the DI design pattern in Java or C# syntax alone, not how any particular DI framework handles this.

For example, let's say I have this class which returns a String (relative path, based on some obscure implementation logic). It (rather its various implementors) has a configuration/initialization dependency on the "projectLocation", as a user could have various projects on their machine and this class will perform some logic based on a given project whenever it is called.

```
public abstract class PathResolver {

    protected File projectFilesLocation;

    public RoutinePathResolver(File projectFilesLocation) {
        this.projectFilesLocation = projectFilesLocation;
    }

    public abstract String getPath(String someValue);
}
```

I am not using DI just for unit-testing (*gasp* I'm not even unit testing, existing project). I just want to separate my dependency/creational concerns and logic concerns period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the thing you want to inject, e.g., a file location, is something that would be directly used by the class then it is perfectly valid to inject it.

In the case of an `Object` such as a `File` or a `String` then this is no different to something called Service. It is a **dependency** of your class thus DI applies.

Comment: But on the other hand, one could inject a ConfigurationSettings interface, which performs the service of returning said String value? Perhaps from a repo, config file, or something else. There would be a difference.

Comment: You could do that but IMHO a ConfigurationSettings interface ends up becoming a God object and you end up with everything depending on it. It's better to inject the specific configuration required for each class directly into it. Maybe if you wanted different ways of loading the file you would have a `FileProvider` interface with `CMSFileProvider` and `LocalSystemFileProvider` implementations for example.

Comment: It depends. It's perfectly fine to have a concrete Config VO. For instance `PathResolvedConfig`. If and only when it exclusively carries config data for that specific class (or interface, obviously). An `ApplicationConfig` VO of which only a part of the data is used is definitely a no-no.

Comment: Good point Creynders, if the config class has a high enough cohesion then it's not a problem and often makes life easier. I tend to use the same rule of thumb for this and the Parameter Object pattern. If you have more than 3 values then encapsulate in a VO.